# Can I use skaffold build with source code that contians docker file

Tags: docker, skaffold

Need to clone some repo say: `git clone abc.git` then switch context to `abc` then use the dockerfile inside `abc` to build using skaffold passing custom `ARGS`.

Is it possible to achieve this via skaffold

for eg:

```yaml
    - name: test-build
      build:
        tagPolicy:
          envTemplate:
            template: 1.0.0
        artifacts:
        - image: dockerhub.io/test-build
          requires:
            command: ["git", "clone", "abc.git"]
          context: ./abc
```

Comment: I dont know skaffold but docker itself can operate on url / git repos. You may be able to use the repo directly https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories

Comment: This helped, I can use this and skaffold custom build command to still build via skaffold and does not need to explicitly clone

Answer (score 1):

This is one way that worked for me by using skaffold custom build

```
- name: test-build
 build:
    tagPolicy:
      envTemplate:
        template: 1.0.0
    artifacts:
    - image: dockerhub.io/test-build
       custom:
          buildCommand: docker build github.com/abc.git#v1
```